# adding category to new created journal article in liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I am trying to add category to new created article. My code is here:

```
ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(
    JournalArticle.class.getName(), 
    actionRequest
);
article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.addArticle(
    ImporterConstants.IMPORTER_ID, 
    ImporterConstants.GROUP_ID, 
    ImporterConstants.DOC_FOLDER_ID,
    titleMap, 
    descMap, 
    content, 
    structureID, 
    templateID, 
    serviceContext
);
AssetEntry ae = AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.fetchEntry(
    JournalArticle.class.getName(), 
    article.getResourcePrimKey()
); //returns AssetEntry
AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.addAssetCategoryAssetEntry(48183, ae);
```

Article is created without problem, but when I try to call

```
 AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.addAssetCategoryAssetEntry(48183, ae)
```

or

```
AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.addAssetEntryAssetCategory(ae.getEntryId(), 48183)
```

it won't bring any results and table `assetentries_assetcategories` is without any changes. Number 48183 is `categoryid`from table `assetcategory.

Can you tell me where can be problem? 
PS: I am using Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2.0 CE GA1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the article asset entry with the required category id

```
AssetEntry updateEntry(
        long userId, long groupId, String className, long classPK,
        String classUuid, long classTypeId, long[] categoryIds,
        String[] tagNames, boolean visible, Date startDate, Date endDate,
        Date publishDate, Date expirationDate, String mimeType,
        String title, String description, String summary, String url,
        String layoutUuid, int height, int width, Integer priority,
        boolean sync)
    throws PortalException, SystemException


assetEntryLocalService.updateEntry(
            userId, entry.getGroupId(), JournalArticle.class.getName(),
            entry.getEntryId(), entry.getUuid(), 0, assetCategoryIds,
            assetTagNames, visible, null, null, entry.getDisplayDate(), null,
            ContentTypes.TEXT_HTML, entry.getTitle(), null, summary, null, null,
            0, 0, null, false);
```